# Rails adds extra <style> tags to the rendered page

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

My application is working perfectly in development environment, but when I switched to production environment I found that the styles look a bit different. After some tracing, I noticed that these tags:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">…</style>
<style type="text/css" media="media">…</style>
<style type="text/css" media="print">…</style>
```

were added to the head tag overriding my application.css styles.

Is there any way to stop these tags from being added to the rendered page?

**Updtae**

**Gemfile**
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
# gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported           runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'devise'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'mysql2'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster.     Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more:     https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
# To include font-awesome icons
# gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
# gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.1.0'

# rails specific capistrano funcitons
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1.0'

# integrate bundler with capistrano
gem 'capistrano-bundler'

# if you are using RBENV
gem 'capistrano-rbenv', "~> 2.0"
gem 'capistrano-rvm'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop
  # execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application
  # running in the background.Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring', '~> 1.3.4'
end
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

**production.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.precompile =  ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb'] 
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

Comment: These tags are not added by standard Rails. Check your layout view, your assets gems and your app configuration which deviates from the Rails defaults. Without more information, we can't really help you though.

Comment: I tried checking all these before posting the question with no luck. Will posting the Gemfile and production.rb files help identify the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the default order in the head tag inside app/views/layouts/application.html.erb from

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

to

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

solved the problem and no extra style tags were added to the rendered page.